# Is it possible to run an R markdown script within VS Code without debugging?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, r-markdown

I've just started using R in VS Code and my script is currently stored as an RMD file. I'm pretty sure I can't debug this as there's no RMD debugger for the version of R I'm using, but when I try to run without debugging (from Run > Run without Debugging / Ctrl + F5) it prompts a dialogue box saying 'You don't have an extension for debugging R Markdown.' Surely I don't need a debugger to run without debugging?

I can obviously still run chunks at a time, or by selecting code, so this is more of an annoyance than a serious issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested and succeeded using Rmarkdown in the VSCode environment. If you use Mac, install this extension below:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TianyiShi.rmarkdown

another reference:

https://towardsdev.com/r-markdown-notebook-in-vs-code-3adb5a61417a

Hope it helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34259064)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).